# Let $A$,$ B$, and $C$ be sets. Show that $(A\setminus B)\setminus C = A\setminus (B\cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

It would be great if I could get some help. I'm not sure what it is I need to do, I know that I need to prove both sides. But do I prove that $x$ is an element of $A$ since $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$ means that $x\in A$.

Comment: Can you give the setup to "prove both sides"?  For example, to show that sets $F$ and $G$ are the same, you can start (i) Suppose $x \in F$.  We want to show that $x \in G$..., (ii) Suppose $x \in G$.  We want to show that...

Comment: Suppose $x$ is an element of the LHS. What does this tell you about which of $A$, $B$, and $C$ it belongs to? Do the same for the RHS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of $(A - B) - C = A - (B \cup C)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172292/proof-of-a-b-c-a-b-cup-c)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with "$\subseteq$": we show that if $x \in(A \setminus B)\setminus C$, then $x \in A \setminus(B \cup C)$.

What can you say about $B$ and $C$ with regards to $x$? Is $x \in B$? It is not, because $x \in(A \setminus B)\setminus C\subseteq (A \setminus B)$, and we know that $(A \setminus B)=\{x \in A : x \notin B\}$. So we conclude $x \notin B$. Can you make a similar argument for $C$? And what can we conclude about $B\cup C$? This should finish the "$\subseteq$" part.

Comment: yay Showing one direction should also give an example on how to do the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

$$x \in (A \setminus B) \setminus C$$

if and only if $$x \in A \setminus B \text{ and } x \notin C$$

if and only if

$$x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B \text{ and } x \notin C$$

if and only if (de Morgan's)

$$x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B \cup C$$

if and only if

$$x\in A\setminus (B \cup C)$$